# When does $| \sum a_n |^2 \ge \sum |a_n|^2$ hold?

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to know when $| \sum a_n |^2 \ge \sum |a_n|^2$ for real numbers .  Obviously it's true when all $a_i's$ are non-negative.  What looser condition is sufficient?

Comment: no looser condition is sufficient, I believe. This is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a few examples:

$$(a + b)^2 \ge a^2 + b^2$$
$$\iff a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \ge a^2 + b^2$$
$$\iff ab \ge 0$$

$$(a + b + c)^2 \ge a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$
$$\iff a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2(ab + bc + ba) \ge a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$
$$\iff ab+bc+ca \ge0$$

In general,

$$\left(\sum a_n\right)^2 - \sum a_n^2 = \sum a_n^2 + 2\sum_{i<j} a_ia_j - \sum a_n^2\\
=2\sum_{i<j} a_ia_j$$

Now,

$$2\sum_{i<j} a_ia_j \ge 0 \iff \sum_{i<j} a_ia_j \ge 0$$

Hence,

$$\left(\sum a_n\right)^2 - \sum a_n^2 \ge 0 \iff \sum_{i<j} a_ia_j \ge 0$$

Rearranging,

$$\left(\sum a_n\right)^2 \ge \sum a_n^2 \iff \sum_{i<j} a_ia_j \ge 0$$

What this says is that it is sufficient for the sum of all pairwise products of elements of $a_n$ to be at least $0$.

Comment: For example (3, 3, -1): (9 - 3 - 3) = 3 > 0 and 25 > 19. It works.